# CSS specificity of :not() pseudo class

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class, css-specificity

I have this small HTML:

```
<div id="column">
    <div class="ticker">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

For `ul` elements outside of the `.ticker` class, but inside of the `#column` id exists this CSS:

```
#column ul:not(.a):not(.b) {
    margin: 1em;
}
```

But inside the `.ticker` class I don't want this margin. So I thought I could use:

```
#column .ticker ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

That said, I know that the specificity of the first CSS selector is higher because of the two `:not()` pseudo classes. But to get a higher specificity I had to append those two `:not()` in the second CSS snippet to the `ul`, too. So that works:

```
#column .ticker ul:not(.c):not(.d) {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Isn't that stupid? In fact it doesn't matter what you use in the two `:not()`pseudo classes. They just have to be there. This doesn't make any sense to me.

Is that simply a part of CSS3 which is not perfect or is there a solution which my brain didn't come up with yet?

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/9BDw5/2/

Comment: You have calculated the CSS specificity correctly so your CSS (though a bit awkward perhaps) is good. There might be a better way of designing the overall CSS scheme, but it depends in part on the HTML structure of the web page in question.

Comment: Yes - psuedoclasses and psuedoelements have the same specificity as their real counterparts.  This is not a CSS issue so much as it's a CSS and markup design/practices issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not just you; this is indeed one of the fundamental pitfalls of specificity as a CSS concept.

A simpler solution that is equally valid would be to repeat your `.ticker` class selector so you have this:

```
#column .ticker.ticker ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

This way you do not have to modify your element to add an extra class just for the sake of increasing selector specificity.

The spec [verifies this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity):

> **Note:** Repeated occurrances of the same simple selector are allowed and do increase specificity.

On a side note, remember that the specificity of the `:not()` pseudo-class is strictly defined (in the same section of the spec) as equal to that of its argument. So `:not(#id)` and `#id` have the same specificity, and likewise for `:not(E):not(.a)` and `E.a`. The `:not` portion does not count at all, not even as a pseudo-class.

This limitation in specificity will be addressed in [Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#specificity-rules), which enhances `:not()` to accept a comma-delimited list of selectors. The specificity of a `:not()` that contains a selector list will be that of the most specific selectors in the list, so the specificity of `ul:not(.c, .d)` is equal to 1 type selector and 1 class selector, compared to `ul:not(.c):not(.d)` which is equal to 1 type selector and 2 class selectors. This makes it tremendously useful in excluding any number of classes from a match.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the note in the CSS spec, good explanation and insight.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative, and somewhat cleaner approach.

Add a fictitious class name to your `div.ticker` element:

```
<div id="column">
    <ul>
        <li>Outside Item 1</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="ticker extra-tag">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and modify the CSS as follows:

```
#column ul:not(.a):not(.b) {
    margin-left: 1em;
}

#column .ticker.extra-tag ul {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

So, the specificity of the first rule is `1-1-2` and for the second rule `1-1-2`.

The two `:not()` count as two classes, so you need to have at least two classes in
the second rule, which I implemented by using the fictitious class name `.extra-tag`.

The fictitious class is probably more computationally efficient than adding the
extra `:not()` pseudo-class.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/7beNx/

Learn more about CSS specificity at: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity

Comment: You don't even have to add the extra class - you can simply repeat `.ticker` so you have `#column .ticker.ticker ul`, which is perfectly acceptable and does give the same specificity bonus. (Shall I post it as a separate answer since it's quite different from yours?)

Comment: @BoltClock Interesting variation, please post with comments, this trick would be very useful for cases where you may not be able to add the extra class name.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above chaining the :not() pseudo-class increases specificity by one each time.

[This article explains it very nicely](http://brettjankord.com/2015/06/07/the-not-css-pseudo-class-and-specificity/)